# NetBeans 8.0 PhoneGap Running Error

Tags: android, netbeans, cordova

I made a Netbeans Phonegap Blank Hello World App but it refuses to run giving me this error when i run using embedded browser:

```
Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail. (22:45:04:262)
at public_html/js/libs/Cordova-2.9.0/cordova-2.9.0.js:6725
Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower  only. (22:45:04:265)
  at public_html/js/libs/Cordova-2.9.0/cordova-2.9.0.js:982
Failed to load resource: Unexpected end of file from server (22:45:04:276 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/cordova_plugins.js
```

Removing

> > > >
> > >       script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/Cordova-2.9.0/cordova-2.9.0.js

makes it not run at all.

I've verified cordova, ant, adb, git, java from the command prompt.
I've installed the latest versions of netbeans,cordova,android sdk,git and ant.

I could not find a solution to this problem

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The hello world template has some bugs that I haven't got the time to figure out why. The other templates work.